# Android Radio Button Text Is Misplaced

Tags: android, layout, radio-button, android-relativelayout, radio-group

I have created a layout which contains some `RadioGroup`s and `RadioButton`s. The `RadioGroup`s' parent layout is `RelativeLayout`, and if it's possible I would like to stay with `RelativeLayout`.

In most of the devices, the circle of the `RadioButton` is in the left of the text, as it has to be, like this:

[image]

But in some devices (I noticed the problem with Samsung devices that are set to Hebrew), the circle is actually **on** the text, like this:

[image]

Here is my code (I deleted other items in the layout which are irrelevant):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/some_color1"
android:gravity="left" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/group1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/key1"
    android:layout_below="@id/key5"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size4"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/u_hour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/hour"
        android:textSize="@dimen/size8" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/u_day"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/day"
        android:textSize="@dimen/size8" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/u_week"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/week"
        android:textSize="@dimen/size8" />
</RadioGroup>
```

I have found nothing helpful with this problem, could please someone show me the way to solve it?

Comment: would you like to post your code or Sherlock homes shall fix it

Comment: OK, I added my layout.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `RelativeLayout`. Try using `LinearLayout` instead. This is the one that is used to arrange objects horizontally or vertically. Check the guides or examples; there are many out there.

I would try it like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:listPreferredItemHeightLarge"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
    android:dividerPadding="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">



<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/u_hour"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/hour"
    android:textSize="@dimen/size8" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/u_day"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/day"
    android:textSize="@dimen/size8" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/u_week"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/week"
    android:textSize="@dimen/size8" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, [here](http://www.thetekblog.com/2010/07/android-radiobutton-in-radiogroup-example/) is a tutorial with an example using a `RadioGroup`.

Comment: `RadioGroup` is actually a subclass of `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Should it help if I add a `LinearLayout` and put the `RadioGroup` in it?

Comment: Why did you change layout_height, showDividers, divider, dividerVertical and dividerPadding?

Comment: It is not necessary. I just used an example that I already had. You can those parameters out if you want.

Comment: And if I just put it in an additional `LinearLayout` which I create? Is it OK?

Comment: I think you are a little confused about how `Layouts` work. You can use nested `LinearLayouts` if you want. That will depend of what your final Layout will be. A `RadioGroup` inside of a `LinearLayout` won't work because as you said is redundant though. Experiment a little bit adding the properties that you like it to have, and take out the ones that are bothering. The only ones that are really important are `gravity` and `orientation`.

Answer (score 0):

I also would recommend to use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` if the bug persists in some devices.